# DIV positioned incorrectly

Tags: css

On my webpage over at http://www.replyonline.co.uk/test/index.html you will see a twitter div named #twitter.

As you can see, it looks out of position and needs to be after the 4 #about divs to the left of it, but also needs to line up with the others. It looks pushed down currently.

I've also put a a div around all of the #about boxes to separate them from the #twitter div.

Here's the CSS for one of the about boxes and the twitter box:

```
#about1{
width: 260px;
min-height: 140px;
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 15px 0;  background: url(../images/about_grad1.jpg) bottom right;
display: block;
 }

#twitter{
width: 220px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
height: 290px;
overflow: auto;
float: right;
font-size: 11px;
background: #ececec;
 }
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive in how you want it to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the twitter div in the same div block as the 4 about boxes

it should be

```
<div>
  <div>box1</div>
  <div>box2</div>
  <div>box3</div>
  <div>box4</div>
  <div>twitter</div>
</div>
```

Then thin it down a little bit or adjust the margins. Not enough horizontal room. 
If you set the #twitter width to 240 you should get everything on one line, then adjust until it looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

see if dis works

```
#twitter {
width: 240px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
height: 290px;
overflow: auto;
font-size: 11px;
background: #ECECEC;
float: right;
margin-top: -310px;
margin-left: 50px;
}
```